# Footnote of several paragraphs length to section title

Tags: sectioning, footnotes

I have a long footnote attached to a section title. It spans three paragraphs. Latex complains `! Paragraph ended before \M@sect was complete.`. What's the best way of doing this, if one has to do it at all? Use `protect` before the footnote and manually break lines via `\\`, but then I have no indentation of second and third paragraph?

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\begin{document}
\paragraph{I am a paragraph\footnote{This footnote has more than one paragraph.

This is the second paragraph.

This is the third paragraph}%end footnote
}%end paragraph
\end{document}
```

Edit:

Trying to follow barbara's suggestion I've done the following, which seems to produce the desired result in my real file, but in the MWE the numbering is off, so I'm worried I'm still missing something here:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\begin{document}

\paragraph{I am a paragraph.\protect\footnotemark}
\footnotetext{This footnote has more than one paragraph.

This is the second paragraph.

This is the third paragraph.}
\end{document}
```

Comment: better to try to handle this with `\footnotemark` in the `\paragraph` argument, and `\footnotetext{...}` separately, outside of the header text.  since `\paragraph` has a "moving argument", the whole thing must be short enough to be copied in one piece into the `.aux` file, and a footnote with multiple paragraphs certainly isn't!

Comment: You could replace the blank lines by `\endgraf`  but I get an erro rfor any footnote here even `\footnote{}` why not put it after the heading?

Comment: @barbarabeeton : Please see my edit.

Comment: @muk.li -- can't figure out why the number on the paragraph isn't being stepped, but there's another way around the problem.  answer posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the "obvious" approach here is to separate this into `\footnotemark` and
`\footnotetext{...}`.  unfortunately, with the example provided, `memoir` delivers a footnote number one lower than it should be in the footnote itself.
a reasonably detailed examination of the `memoir` code for `\paragraph` and footnotes failed to uncover the reason.

but there's another straightforward way to handle this: 
keep the whole footnote within the `\paragraph` argument, but
don't use blank lines to separate the paragraphs.  instead,
use `\protect\endgraf` to indicate the divisions.

here we illustrate both approaches.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\setlength{\textheight}{2.25in}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
some text

\paragraph{I am a paragraph.\protect\footnote
{This footnote has more than one paragraph.\protect\endgraf
This is the second paragraph.\protect\endgraf
This is the third paragraph.}}

some text

\paragraph{I am a paragraph.\protect\footnotemark}
\footnotetext{This footnote has more than one paragraph.

This is the second paragraph.

This is the third paragraph.}

some text

\end{document}
```

[image: output of example code]

Answer (score 2):

Fool TeX into not seeing `\par` (or a blank line) in the argument to the sectional command.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\newcommand{\footnoted}[3]{%
  % #1 is the sectional command
  % #2 is the title
  % #3 is the footnote
  \long\def\next{#3}%
  #1[#2]{#2\footnote{\next}}%
}

\begin{document}

\footnoted\paragraph{I am a paragraph}
  {This footnote has more than one paragraph.

   This is the second paragraph.

   This is the third paragraph.}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\begin{document}
\paragraph[zzz]{I am a paragraph\footnote{This footnote has more than one paragraph.
This is the second paragraph.
%
This is the third paragraph}%end footnote
}%end paragraph _heading_
stuff here
\end{document}
```